# How to replace a pure component with shouldComponentUpdate in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following react component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Backdrop from 'components/ui/backdrop/backdrop.component';

class BaseModal extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps: INextProps) {
    return nextProps.show !== this.props.show || nextProps.children !== this.props.children;
  }

  render() {
    const { show, modalClosed } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <Backdrop show={show} onClick={modalClosed} />

        <div
          className='modalClass'
          style={{
            transform: show ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100vh)',
            opacity: this.props.show ? '1' : '0',
          }}>
          >{this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

interface IProps {
  show: boolean;
  modalClosed: boolean;
  children: any;
}

interface INextProps {
  show: boolean;
  children: any;
}

export default BaseModal;
```

I would like to use a pure component here. Does that mean that I can remove the shouldComponentUpdate life cycle method from this component? If so, how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely remove the shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle method here. This lifecycle shouldn't usually be used if all you do is compare props by reference, you can safely replace it's functionality by using PureComponent (read more about when you should use either https://codeburst.io/when-to-use-component-or-purecomponent-a60cfad01a81)

You can also remove INextProps interface, as it isn't actually needed (you should use the same interface IProps in shouldComponentUpdate as well).

Here an improved version to your component, which uses PureComponent instead of Component.

```
import React from 'react';

import Backdrop from 'components/ui/backdrop/backdrop.component';

class BaseModal extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { show, modalClosed, children } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <Backdrop show={show} onClick={modalClosed} />

        <div
          className='modalClass'
          style={{
            transform: show ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100vh)',
            opacity: show ? '1' : '0',
          }}>
          >
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

interface IProps {
  show: boolean;
  // by the way you are using it, it seems like modalClosed is a function not a bool
  modalClosed: () => void;
  children: any;
}

export default BaseModal;
```